# positioning a div when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eDyHf/1/

```
$("#ninjaimage1").draggable({
    containment: "#cirlce1",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $("#cirlce1").animate({
            top: $(this).offset().top,
            left: $(this).offset().left
        });
    }
});
```

my question is that when I drag the image inside the div I want the image stay always in the center of the div how can I achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is that what you are looking for? (otherwise you must provide a more precise explanation of your problem!)

http://jsfiddle.net/u4CBW/

simply add +60 to the values to change the circle position correctly:

```
$("#cirlce1").animate({ top: $(this).offset().top-60, left: $(this).offset().left-60 });
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add the two divs inside each other and only append the drag event to the outer (circle)? then it will always stay in the center, without big effort in javascript, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ebnz/

HTML:

```
<div id="field">
    <div id="cirlce1" class="circlle">
        <img id="ninjaimage1" class="Ninjaimg" src="http://www.boursematch.com/assets/images/avatar_default.gif"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Ninjaimg {
        position:relative;
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        display:block;
        cursor:pointer;
        z-index:3000;
    }
    .circlle {
        position: absolute;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border:1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:1;
        display:block;
    }
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cirlce1").draggable();
        });
```

Comment: because the div should be dragged based on the image and not vise versa when the image is dragged the circle should be dragged and it's new center will be the coordinate of the image

Comment: in my scenario the image should be dragged only withing the circle and when the drag end it's new position is the center of the circle